# Magento: Order IDs start with 00000

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

Magento 1.5.1.0: After I installed Aitoc's Pre-Orders module, I suddenly from time to time get order numbers such as 00000002, 00000004 (where order numbers usually begin with 4 or 6). It's only a small subset of customers that get these order numbers, but the problem is that in our payment system the orders are registered with a different order number.

What I can do to debug what's going on? Where are order numbers set?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Look for a override of Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Increment/Numeric.php in your Module.

Regards boti

Answer (score 0):

You can update your eav_entity_type table.

```
 update `eav_entity_type` set `increment_pad_length`=4 where `entity_type_code`='order';
```